# A button shadow and text like the Apple App Store on Android

Tags: android, android-button

Id like a button shadow and text like the Apple App Store.
Does anyone know how I could achieve this in android studio?

Like the images below, id like to have a button with an image as a background with a **greyed** out section over the image and text over the top of the greyed out area with that nice shadowing like on the apple App Store.

I have a button I have created in Xcode to demonstrate what I mean.

I know how to do this in Xcode but I'm lost in android studio.

[image: likethis]
[image: appAppStore]

help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41865518/6891563

Comment: @Khemraj thanks for the reply, but the image is the background and I want that to be 100% occupancy I only want the grey section above to be somewhat transparent with text over the top of that. Like the image above :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody ok no probs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put item in the cardView, with elevation

like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will have to try it tomorrow when I get a chance (it’s 12am atm)

Comment: Would you know how to get the grey rectangle over the image with text over the top in card view? Would you nest another card view or something?

Comment: you should put ConstraintLayout in this cardview, then, put anything you want on it

Comment: I have had a browse on the internet and card view is exactly what I want, and that shadow should look , I’ll need to watch a few vids but this is the right answer I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make it through the `ConstraintLayout` with shapes.

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <ImageView/>
  <TextView/>
  <!-- bg for text in the bottom of the view -->
  <View/> 
</ConstraintLayout>
```

The main idea is providing `ShapeAppearanceModel` and setting it programmatically as `backgroundDrawable` for the `ConstraintLayout` (and apply some elevation in the XML).

Comment: This is a another great way to do it. Thanks for putting in the time to answer :), I am gonna try card view as answered before but if I cant get it to work I’ll try this.

Comment: as you wish but `CardView` is a bit of an overhead (my personal opinion).

Comment: An Overhead? Is it difficult to implement? I do want to use the easiest way possible because it just now worth it if it is to troublesome.

Comment: again, it's your choice. You should care not only about the difficulty lvl of implementation but also about performance.

Comment: Which in you opinion preforms better and overall looks better?

Comment: definitely not the `CardView` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ViewOutlineProvider` with method `setOutlineProvider` and create any shape you want there. Then to add shadow you just need to apply elevation on it.